# how to remove data from a dataset table where is relation

Tags: asp.net, dataset

I have a dataset with two tables and between these tables there is a relation:

```
 DataColumn dc1;
        DataColumn dc2;

        dc1 = q.Tables[0].Columns["dateFrom"];
        dc2 = q.Tables[1].Columns["dateFrom"];
        DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("tracker", dc1, dc2, false);
```

Now I want to remove from the first table all the rows that don't have a data in the second table. How can I do that?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to rather just return the valid data in the first place? `INNER JOIN` probably would suit you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do that in the first place? You might lose important data in this case (unless you know it's unnecessary content).
I assume that if there's data in the parent table then it must have been added for reason, or there might be a problem in your code. Have a look at that and try to avoid having dirty data.

With regards to your question, I would loop throug the main records and check if there's any parent records. At the same time compare and make sure the data can be deleted.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but you may get an idea from the below (you may not even need to set the relation)

```
var results = from table1 in q.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
              join table2 in q.Tables[1].AsEnumerable() on table1["dateFrom"] equals table2["dateFrom"]                  
             select new { 
               dateFrom = table1["dateFrom"], 
               // anyother columns                 
              };
```

Hope this helps and good luck

Krishna